# How to get Seller Name from Amazon in ItemSearch using Amazon Product API

Tags: asp.net, amazon-product-api

How can I get the Seller name using the Amazon API in ASP.NET? Which response group do I need to use, and what kind of parameters are necessary for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get the seller name of an **offer listing**. To do this you need to use the `OfferFull` response group as well as the `MerchantId` parameter set to `All` and the `Condition` parameter set to `All`. If you don't set the `MerchantId` you will only get Amazon listings and if you don't set the `Condition` parameter you will only get New listings.

Request:

```
http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?
Service=AWSECommerceService&
AWSAccessKeyId=[AWS Access Key ID]&
Operation=ItemLookup&
ItemId=B00008OE6I&
ResponseGroup=OfferFull&                 <- important
MerchantId=All&                          <- important
Condition=All&                           <- important
&Timestamp=[YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ]
&Signature=[Request Signature]
```

In your response you will need to look at the `Items > Item > Offers > Offer > Merchant > Name` node.

```
<Items>
    ...
    <Item>
        ...
        <Offers>
            <TotalOffers>148</TotalOffers>
            <TotalOfferPages>15</TotalOfferPages>
            <Offer>
                <Merchant>
                    <MerchantId>[Merchant Id]</MerchantId>
                    <Name>[Merchant Name]</Name>
                    ...
                </Merchant>
             ...
            </Offer>
       ...
```

Comment: If you are reading this in 2017 or later - you can no longer get a list of all offers through the ItemLookup call. Nowadays, the best case scenario is to get 1 offer(the lowest priced one) for each possible product condition(New, Used, Refurbished, Collectible). 

If you want to get a list of all offers, you need to set the ResponseGroup parameter to Small, follow the All Offers link returned by the API, and parse the HTML to extract the data.

Comment: Can I get seller name by "GetCompetitivePricingForASIN"? I only see two parameters.

Comment: @Kun-yaoWang It's been a while since I've worked with this API. Try posting a new question.